# jQuery carousel where elements are shown and hidden with slide effect are jumpy and are shown outside of viewport

Tags: jquery, slide, carousel

I think [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/pQRUe/7/) says it all .

The requirement is to show recent forum posts in a carousel.

I would like to either get pointed to a jQuery plugin that I can use or if someone could improve the animation for me.

Notes:

- I cannot change the markup to an ul-li list.
- The elements are divs or spans and contain some text and a link
- The surrounding div, i.e. the viewport, can have a static height

Regards,
Mathias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/justiceerolin/nAAEs/

I changed the following:

- Added `overflow:hidden` to parent element
- Set `slideElement` to specific height (based on parent element)
- Used `.slideUp`, instead of hide/show Put show before `.slideUp`

Comment: Thanks Justice. Great improvments. Is it also possible to push the old message up so the new message just won't go on top?

Comment: If that's the effect that you want to do, I'd suggest you look into animating "scrollTop" for that specific div.

Comment: I think I'm going to go with http://jsfiddle.net/Vx3Cb/1/. Seems sliding left doesn't have the jump problem. Thanks for the help.